# Statement lambdas cannot be converted to expression trees in Workflow Foundation 4.0

Tags: vb.net, lambda, workflow-foundation-4

I've been pulling my hair out on this for awhile. I have a custom activity that accepts an InArgument like such:

```
[RequiredArgument]
public InArgument<Func<IDataReader, T>> Projection { get; set; }
```

And later on I use this Projection in a Select statement on a data reader after an SQL query like so:

```
results = reader.Select<T>(context.GetValue(this.Projection)).ToList();
```

Now, the only difficult part is actually passing the func variable in the VB expression. Specifically in this case, T is a list of RawTie objects. But every time I try to do something complicated with the expression to assemble a list from the reader, I get the error: Statement Lambda Functions are not supported in this context.

Here is an example of an expression I attempted. Keeping in mind VB is not my primary language:

```
Function(r As IDataReader) As New List(Of RawTie)
    Dim ties As New List(Of RawTie)()

    Do While r.Read()
        'Do something with the ties
    Loop

    r.Close()

    Return ties

End Function
```

Is there any information on, at least, whether this is a VB problem or a WWF problem? Just ask if you need more information.

Comment: Can you change your in-argument Projection from Func to Expression-Of-Func? A Func is compiled into the il, an expression is an in-memory representation of the specified function, and therefore something different.

Comment: Still no good. I can use Expression Of Func on the C# side, I think, but I'm still getting the same error with the input.